# Unity player movement issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to follow brackeys tutorial on player controller, but the code is not working.
[image]

Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Mouse_Look : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float mousesen = 100f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    float xRotation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * mousesen;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * mousesen;
        
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f , 90f );
        
        transform.localRotation=Quaternion.Euler(xRotation,0f,0f);
        playerBody.Rotate=(Vector3 up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

`transform.Rotate` is a method, not a property, so
`playerBody.Rotate=(Vector3 up * mouseX);`

should be
`playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX, playerBody.rotation.y, playerBody.rotation.y);`

Comment: there's a new error 
Assets\Scripts\lookmouse.cs(28,27): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'float'

Comment: @Ashitoshbendre Try without `Vector3.up`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `playerBody.Rotate()` instead of `playerBody.Rotate=()`.

[Unity transform.Rotate documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

Answer (score 0):

This `playerBody.Rotate=(Vector3 up * mouseX);`
Should be `playerBody.Rotate(Vector3 up * mouseX);`

Rotate is method that takes in a vector 3. I suggest taking some time to understand the basics of [rotation in Unity](https://vionixstudio.com/2022/06/16/unity-quaternion-and-rotation-guide/), rather than just copy pasting codes from tutorial. This might fix the error, but you will have to look for tutorial every time.

Answer (score 0):

`playerBody.Rotate=(Vector3 up * mouseX); to playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);` because ".Rotate" is method. you don't need "=". :) cheers mate!